# Confused about rsync no-perm alike option

Tags: linux, rsync

Trying to upload files without update perms/owner with this options:

```
--no-perms --no-owner --no-group -avz
```

It works well except it changes perms and owner, which is weird.

Something wrong with my rsync?
Reinstalled and get same results.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are providing options to not change perms/owner, but after this you override them.

`-a` option is mean archive, and it implies perms/owner options implicitly.

use

```
-avz --no-perms --no-owner --no-group
```

instead

Comment: awesome! worked, thsnks. i'm feeling so dumb...